# Searching for CRUD tutorials

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring, crud

I am sorry for my terrible English.

I ask for help with the following task: write a web application that would execute sql queries to the database: select, update, insert and other basic operations. About the interface - the text field where the request is entered and then performed after the click of a button. It is also required to provide registration pages, plus different functionality for the administrator and the regular user.

From the "technique" it is recommended to use Java + Spring Framework, TypeScript + Angular, MySQL. However, the problem is that from all that list I have worked only with Java and MySQL. In short, I have a little experience with the front-end (HTML, CSS, JS), but haven't yet tried working with back-end. So I am completely newbie with all this.

Therefore, I ask for help with some good tutorials on this topic. Alas, there is no way that I could raise all this from scratch. I just have no enough time for it. Please share with me tutorials that really helped you and do not throw the first links from Google. I am able to find those in a search engine myself, but I regularly find outdated or too complicated for a beginner.

Comment: Hi, I guess your question is too broad and a bit contradictory because you are asking for help and at the same time won't accept the first links from Google which are generally acceptable.  It would be better for you to ask for clarification if you've found something _too complicated_ and provide the evidence of your effort.  Btw, your English is quite good! :)

Comment: I have mentioned the task because I'm not sure that I'm even searching for the right thing. Maybe such task is better characterised in another word not CRUD.

The problem is that a lot of first link tutorials don't show the structure of the program. And I just don't know what to do with all those files and in which folders put them.

Comment: For example this tutorial is quite useless for me because of the reasons I mentioned.
https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-crud-example

I can download the sourcecode to see the structure of the program. But it will be just a pile of files for me cause I don't know how to run it.